# Fetch Redirecting to Root

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a page with a sort order option on it. I'm trying to make it so that when you change the sort order, it re-fetches the `fetch` request and updates the data. Though, when doing so below, it's redirecting me to `/` root instead of staying on the same page.

```js
watch: {    
  getSortOption(newSortOption) {
    console.log(' Your Saved Sorting = ' + newSortOption)
    this.sortOption = newSortOption
    this.$fetch();
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Surely `this` references the page?

Comment: What is the page your are currently in? What do you have in your `fetch()` hook? Do you see anything in your devtools (error, weird Vue state)? Can you try to manually toggle the thing with a button? Do you have some router guards/middlewares?

Comment: @kissu I'm in `/page/feed` added fetch hook.

Comment: `/page` or `/pages`? It should be the second.